# Firefox not using one rule from userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, css

I've edited my userChrome file

`cat .mozilla/firefox/<someletters>.<profilename>/chrome/userChrome.css`

```
/* Shrink tab titles by 10% */
.tabbrowser-tabs .tab-text {
          font-size: 90%;
}
#tabbrowser-tabs {
  min-height: 16px !important;
}
```

But they are not applying. It doesn't even seem to be the case of not being specific enough. When I inspect the element with DOM inspector I don't even see it applied.

What am I doing wrong here? What is the correct way to change the tab bar height with userChrome.css file?

Answer (score 0):

Three problems I see:

1. You're missing "!important" on the first rule.
2. "min-height" = minimum height = if the default height was under 16px, it would become 16px; since it's not, your rule has no effect. You're looking for "height" or "max-height".
3. You'll need to shrink the favicon as well, or the tab text will be clipped.

Final code:

```
tab .tab-text { font-size: 90% !important; }
tabs, tab .tab-image-left { max-height: 16px !important; }
```

Be aware that the new Firefox UI, Australis, doesn't like to be resized. This code will work in Pale Moon and Firefox with [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/), but probably won't in stock Firefox.

Comment: 1. i assumed userChrome had precedence over page/XUL styles. so i only need important if i'm overriding other rules in userChrome?  2. i couldn't now see any height over the original 30 or 16 while probing with domi... let me try your code.

Comment: To clarify, "no '!important' on the first rule" was one of the problems I saw. I've gone ahead and edited point 1 for clarity.